# Find the top n elements for attribute combination in data frame spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame like below.

```
    scala> ds.show
    +----+----------+----------+-----+
    | key|attribute1|attribute2|value|
    +----+----------+----------+-----+
    |mac1|        A1|        B1|   10|
    |mac2|        A2|        B1|   10|
    |mac3|        A2|        B1|   10|
    |mac1|        A1|        B2|   10|
    |mac1|        A1|        B2|   10|
    |mac3|        A1|        B1|   10|
    |mac2|        A2|        B1|   10|
    +----+----------+----------+-----+
```

For each value in attribute1, I want to find the top N keys and the aggregated value for that key.
Output: 
aggregated value for key for attribute1 will be

```
    +----+----------+-----+
    | key|attribute1|value|
    +----+----------+-----+
    |mac1|        A1|   30|
    |mac2|        A2|   20|
    |mac3|        A2|   10|
    |mac3|        A1|   10|
    +----+----------+-----+
```

Now if N = 1 then the output will be A1 - (mac1,30) A2-(mac2,20)

How to achieve this in DataFrame/Dataset ?
I want to achieve this for all the attributes. In the above example I want to find for attribute1 and attribute2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Given the input `dataframe` as

```
+----+----------+----------+-----+
|key |attribute1|attribute2|value|
+----+----------+----------+-----+
|mac1|A1        |B1        |10   |
|mac2|A2        |B1        |10   |
|mac3|A2        |B1        |10   |
|mac1|A1        |B2        |10   |
|mac1|A1        |B2        |10   |
|mac3|A1        |B1        |10   |
|mac2|A2        |B1        |10   |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
```

and doing `aggregation` on the above input `dataframe` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val groupeddf = df.groupBy("key", "attribute1").agg(sum("value").as("value"))
```

should give you

```
+----+----------+-----+
|key |attribute1|value|
+----+----------+-----+
|mac1|A1        |30.0 |
|mac3|A1        |10.0 |
|mac3|A2        |10.0 |
|mac2|A2        |20.0 |
+----+----------+-----+
```

now you can use `Window` function to generate ranks for each row in grouped data and `filter` rows with `rank <= N` as

```
val N = 1

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("attribute1").orderBy($"value".desc)

groupeddf.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec))
  .filter($"rank" <= N)
  .drop("rank")
```

which should give you the `dataframe` you desire.

```
+----+----------+-----+
|key |attribute1|value|
+----+----------+-----+
|mac2|A2        |20.0 |
|mac1|A1        |30.0 |
+----+----------+-----+
```